# user created with admin rights but getting permission denied error

Tags: server, permissions, users

I have a created user which has admin access. For some hosts the linux commands work seamlessly, but for some systems when the command is entered it shows permission denied:

```
praveen.kumar@chn_lab:/home/admin$ free -m |grep Mem |awk '{print $3/$2 * 100.0}',
bash: /usr/bin/awk: Permission denied
praveen.kumar@mum_lab:~$ free -m |grep Mem |awk '{print $3/$2 * 100.0}'
53.9168
```

Permissions of working machine:

```
praveen.kumar@mum_lab:~$ cat /etc/passwd
admin:x:1003:1000::/home/admin:/bin/bash
praveen.kumar:x:1004:1000:praveen.kumar:/home/praveen.kumar:/bin/bash
```

Permissions of machine with error:

```
praveen.kumar@chn_lab:~$ cat /etc/passwd
admin:x:1002:1000::/home/admin:/bin/bash
praveen.kumar:x:1011:1000::/home/praveen.kumar:/bin/bash
```

How to rectify this permission denied error for the user created same as an admin user?

Replying to @artur-meinild - please find the outputs below:

```
praveen.kumar@chn_lab:~$ pwd
/home/praveen.kumar

praveen.kumar@chn_lab:~$ free -m |grep Mem |awk '{print $3/$2 * 100.0}'
-bash: /usr/bin/awk: Permission denied

praveen.kumar@chn_lab:~$ stat /usr/bin/awk
  File: ‘/usr/bin/awk’ -> ‘/etc/alternatives/awk’
  Size: 21              Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   symbolic link
Device: fc00h/64512d    Inode: 13762578    Links: 1
Access: (0777/lrwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2022-11-15 13:15:01.597965097 +0530
Modify: 2017-06-29 19:02:55.708005841 +0530
Change: 2017-06-29 19:02:55.708005841 +0530
 Birth: -
```

Replying to @Artur

```
praveen.kumar@chn_lab:~$ stat /etc/alternatives/awk
  File: ‘/etc/alternatives/awk’ -> ‘/usr/bin/gawk’
  Size: 13              Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   symbolic link
Device: fc00h/64512d    Inode: 62916691    Links: 1
Access: (0777/lrwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2022-11-15 15:12:01.795430384 +0530
Modify: 2021-01-09 14:56:38.459865499 +0530
Change: 2021-01-09 14:56:38.459865499 +0530
 Birth: -
praveen.kumar@chn_lab:~$
```

replying to  user68186:

```
praveen.kumar@chn_lab:~$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.2 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

replying to @artur

```
praveen.kumar@chn_lab:~$ stat /usr/bin/gawk
  File: ‘/usr/bin/gawk’
  Size: 441512          Blocks: 864        IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fc00h/64512d    Inode: 13767920    Links: 1
Access: (0110/---x--x---)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: ( 1001/versa_priv)
Access: 2022-11-15 10:15:01.635322812 +0530
Modify: 2013-07-03 02:12:04.000000000 +0530
Change: 2022-06-04 10:11:36.905723865 +0530
 Birth: -
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your `/usr/bin/gawk` has invalid permissions.

Do:

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/gawk
```

Then it will run.

Comment: Thanks! this works in lab, let me validate the same in my production environment and revert back

Comment: Please ask a new question, and provide all relevant details. Thanks.